# Unable to load successive .blend files in same instance of blender

Tags: blender

So I'm working on a script that loads some blend files from a directory and processes each one. However, for some reason, after processing the first file blender just quits and does not process the other files.
My main file looks like:

```py
import os
import sys
import argparse
import utils
import bpy

def get_blend_files(dirpath):
    blend_files = filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.blend'), os.listdir(dirpath))
    blend_files = [os.path.join(dirpath, file) for file in blend_files]
    return blend_files

def parse_args(parser):
    argv = sys.argv
    _tmp_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)[0]
    argv = argv[argv.index('--') + 1:]
    if _tmp_args.background:
        argv.append('-b')
    return parser.parse_args(argv)

if __name__=='__main__':
    # Parse arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--background', action='store_true', help='Run in background mode')
    parser.add_argument('-src', '--source', type=str, help='Blend source directory')
    args = parse_args(parser)

    # Load blender filepaths
    blend_files = get_blend_files(args.source)

    # Open test script in blender text editor
    bpy.ops.text.open(filepath=os.path.join(dir_name, 'test.py'))
    test_script = bpy.data.texts['test.py']

    # Run the test script for each .blend file in the directory
    for i, filepath in enumerate(blend_files):
        sys.argv = [i, filepath]
        exec(test_script.as_string())
    bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()
```

And the test file looks like:

```py
import sys
import os
import bpy

if __name__=='__main__':
    path = sys.argv[1]
    if os.path.exists(path):
        print('blendfile ' + str(sys.argv[0]), 'ran')
        bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=path)
```

To run this I just use `blender --python main.py -- -src [blend_directory_path]`. If I comment out the `open_mainfile` command the print statement prints for each blend file in directory. However, if its there then I just get a print for only the first file that is opened

Comment: You lose your text object when you load other file. Copy text into string, or don't use blender's text file loading at all - you can open file in python with `open`.

Comment: @keltar thanks, that was indeed the issue.

Comment: Use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) in a loop to open each file with blender and to run the same script each time. Similar to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/95105/935). You can also get similar results with a shell script. See blenders [CLI options](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html).